# SQL Server Jobs only finishing after I restart the Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have 13 Sql jobs that run at night starting at 11:30pm. Most of them never finish. When I restart the sql agent job it and run the jobs manually it will run but when they run on their own they will continue to run until I stop them. I have a couple that ran for a full 24hours. Does anyone know how I can fix this ?

I have restarted the sql agent, I have checked the blocked, I have run all the SSIS packages in Visual Studio and they are running.

Comment: All tasks start at the same time?

Comment: no the tasks start at 1130pm and start every hour until 215pm 11 Am the next dat

Answer (score 0):

With the minimum provided information you posted i think that you should check what job steps do on finish.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this and these are all set to quit the job reporting success.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue in the past, there was one intermediate step,
say e.g. Step 3, for that step "On Success" event was set to "Go to Step 1", this resulted in an Infinite loop.
So make sure to check for each step "On Success" and "On Failure" events, and also make sure that last step is set to "Quit the job reporting success".

Comment: I have tried this and these are all set to quit the job reporting success.

Comment: Are the job getting stuck on any particular Step? 
What do you see when you go to job history?

Comment: That's the weird part. I was able to get some of them to succeed if i manually ran them on their own and others will fail at different steps than others. Less than a month ago this was working just fine but all of a sudden they stopped working. That's what's so confusing to me. Each day I'm having to restart either the server or the job agents themselves.